# C# Linq order by with new mapped value

Tags: c#, linq

I have List of Orders, which have the property "Status" which is an int. For each status I have a translations in different languages. I want to sort my list by the selected translation and not by numeric status value. What is the best practice here?

```cs
public record OrderTranslation
{
    public string   OrderStatus       { get; set; }
    public string   StatusDescription { get; set; }
    public Language Language          { get; set; }
}
    
public record Order 
{
    public int? Id     { get; set; }
    public int  Status { get; set; }
        
    // I have added a new value to set the translated value and I want to order by this
    public string TranslatedStatusValue { get; set;}
}
```

my function:

```cs
public async Task<FilterResult> FilterAsync(FilterRequest filterRequest, List<string> filterProperties, Language selectedLanguage)
{
    var orderTranslations = dataContext
        .OrderTranslations
        .Where(ot => ot.Language == selectedLanguage)
        .ToList();
    
    var orders = dataContext.Orders.AsNoTracking();
    
    foreach (var order in orders)
    {
        var description = orderTranslations
            .Single(x => x.OrderStatus == serviceContract.Status)
            .StatusDescription;

        serviceContract.TranslatedValue = description;
    }

    // The TranslatedValue is always empty here
    // This is not working, but I want to Order by the translation. Is there another possibility to to this, not using an extra property?
    IQueryable<ServiceContractOrder> query = orders
        .OrderBy("TranslatedStatusValue", filterRequest.IsSortAscending)
        .WhereMatchesFilter(filterRequest, filterProperties);
                             
    result.FilterHits = await query
        .Skip(filterRequest.ItemsToSkip())
        .Take(filterRequest.ItemsPerPage)
        .Cast<object>()
        .ToListAsync();

    result.TotalCount = await query.CountAsync();
    result.ObjectType = typeof(Order).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    result.FilteredProperties = filterProperties;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by sort "my list by the selected translation". Which fields in selected translation do you want orderby and then thenby

Comment: I have made changes in my code. I want to order by translation and not by the int (status)

Comment: `Cast<object>()` <-- _Ewwww_ - why are you doing this?

Comment: Also, when using `Skip` and `Take` with EF use the `Expression<>` versions: i.e. `.Skip( () =>  filterRequest.ItemsToSkip() ).Take( () => filterRequest.ItemsPerPage )` as that will generate better (parameterized) SQL which works better with the SQL Server querystore.

Comment: Also, why are you using _mutable_ record-types? and what version of EF/EFCore are you using? And what is your RDBMS? And why are you using `.AsNoTracking()`?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your size of data and what you want to achieve.

If you have small data set, without pagination, you can sort them in client side ( in your dotnet code).

If you have a large dataset, and/or you need pagination, then you will need to apply the sorting to the DB. In such case, I would suggest you to store the translated values in Same table as Owned Entity or maybe different table. And then you can apply sorting in your LINQ query.

Two benefits you get is,

- Sorting is absolute, and order is maintained across queries.
- Performance, as sorting on client-side hurts for large data sets.

What you lose,

- Any change to translation has to be applied to DB. This makes your database complex.

If the order status is a fixed set of data, like `enum`, then you can chose to have a denormalized design. i.e., to have a dedicated `OrderStatus` table with translations and then join them to your Order table.

Your domain will be somewhat like,

```cs
public record OrderStatus
{
   int Id{get; set;}
   public ISet<OrderTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public record OrderTranslation(Language Language, string)
{
    public string   OrderStatus       { get; set; }
    public string   StatusDescription { get; set; }
    public Language Language          { get; set; }
}
    
public record Order 
{
    public int? Id     { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus  Status { get; set; }
}
```